# Drawing a string with full justified in .NET

Tags: .net, system.drawing, drawstring, text-justify

I need to sraw a string to a bitmap with full justified. I know that StringFormat.Alignment doesn't support full justified alignment. So, I'm looking for a solution to draw a string on a bitmap with full-justify. RictTextBox has full justify but I think it uses WinAPI to justify the text. Maybe I can draw the text with RichTextBox but I don't know how to get the controls bitmap(screenshot) without displaying in the form. 
Is there any trick or an alternative 3rd party library to System.Drawing.Graphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a method to draw `RichTextBox` on a bitmap.

```
public class ExtendedRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    private const double inch = 1440 / 96;//Not 14.4!!, believe me you can see someone use 1.44 but it doesn't work on big bitmaps. They round the 1440/96 as 14.4 but it works on only small sized works. use /96

    public void DrawToBitmap(Graphics graphics, Rectangle bound)
    {
        Update();  // Ensure RTB fully painted
        IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();
        FORMATRANGE fmtRange;

        RECT rect;
        rect.Left = (int)Math.Ceiling(bound.X * inch);
        rect.Top = (int)Math.Ceiling(bound.Y * inch);
        rect.Right = (int)Math.Ceiling(bound.Right * inch);
        rect.Bottom = (int)Math.Ceiling(bound.Bottom * inch);
        int fromAPI;

        fmtRange.hdc = hDC;
        fmtRange.hdcTarget = hDC;

        fmtRange.chrg.cpMin = 0;
        fmtRange.chrg.cpMax = -1;
        fmtRange.rc = rect;
        fmtRange.rcPage = rect;

        IntPtr lParam = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(fmtRange));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(fmtRange, lParam, false);
        fromAPI = SendMessage(Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, 0, lParam);
        fromAPI = SendMessage(Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, 1, lParam);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lParam);
        fromAPI = SendMessage(Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, 0, new IntPtr(0));
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
    }
}
```

You can find WinApi implementations on pinvoke website. But you can take here too:

```
[DllImport("USER32.dll")]
private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private const int WM_USER = 0x400;
private const int EM_FORMATRANGE = WM_USER + 57;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct CHARRANGE
{
    public int cpMin;
    public int cpMax;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct FORMATRANGE
{
    public IntPtr hdc;
    public IntPtr hdcTarget;
    public RECT rc;
    public RECT rcPage;
    public CHARRANGE chrg;
}
```

And here is the example of using.

```
var richtext = new ExtendedRichTextBox(); 
/*I've implemented a RichTextBox but it isn't realted with this question. 
You can use simply RichTextBox. ExtendedRichTextBox has support rtl.*/

richtext.Font = font;
richtext.ForeColor = textColor;
richtext.Text = sometext;
richtext.SelectAll();
richtext.RightToLeft = rtl;
richtext.SelectionAlignment = align;

//Fix the rtl bug in RichTextBox
if (rtl == RightToLeft.Yes)
{
    if (align == TextAlign.Center)
        richtext.Rtf = richtext.Rtf.Replace(@"\qr", @"\qc");
    else if (align == TextAlign.Left)
        richtext.Rtf = richtext.Rtf.Replace(@"\qr", @"\ql");
    else if (align == TextAlign.Justify)
        richtext.Rtf = richtext.Rtf.Replace(@"\qr", @"\qj");
}

//textRect is where we want to put text in.
var tempBitmap = new Bitmap(textRect.Width, textRect.Height);
richtext.DrawToBitmap(Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap), tempRect);
tempBitmap.MakeTransparent(richtext.BackColor);
graph.DrawImage(tempBitmap, panelRect.X, panelRect.Y);
```

Comment: What is **align** and **TextAlign** in example. does your solution address **Justified Alignment** ?